# Input from some text areas for highcharts tooltip

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors, highcharts, tooltip

I am making a highcharts line graph in which tooltip for the points will be taken dynamically from the user through text areas placed inside a jQuery UI dialog.I have made 2 colums of text areas and i want tooltip to be taken form the text-areas in the second column which are palced inside a form.I tried this by specifying the form id of the 2nd column of text areas with an input selector but it's not working.I tried this under the tooltip section of highcharts.

Tool tip code..

```
           tooltip: {
           formatter: function () {
            var serieI = this.series.index;
          var index = dataValues.indexOf(this.y);
         var index1= dataValues2.indexOf(this.y);
          debugger;
            var comment = "";
            if (serieI == 0) {
                comment = $("#ppForm.textarea:eq(" + (index) + ")").val();
            } else {
               //comment = "second serie matched!";
                comment = $("#ppForm.textarea:eq(" + (index1) + ")").val();
            }
            /*return ''+ this.x +
                '</b> is <b>' + this.y + '</b> -->' + comment;*/
            return '-->'+comment;
        }
    }
```

The js fidddle is given here..http://jsfiddle.net/RbenU/24/

Answer (score 1):

You just missed one space as below

```
if (serieI == 0) {
                    comment = $("#ppForm textarea:eq(" + (index) + ")").val();
                } else {
                   //comment = "second serie matched!";
                    comment = $("#ppForm textarea:eq(" + (index1) + ")").val();
                }
```

Check working sample 
http://jsfiddle.net/RbenU/25/

Comment: Thanks...can you tell me how to wrap the tooltip taken from these text areas??Is there any word wrap property for this??

Comment: In you tooltip set `useHTML:true` and set css as in example http://jsfiddle.net/RbenU/26/

Comment: Is the css property set in ur code or do i have to add it in the css section??

Comment: You can write inline css as well as write in css file and apply css class to tooltip div.

Comment: ok.I have a query,I'm trying to make points under different x axis value have different tooltip .As you can see in your code the 1st two points of series 1 have the same tooltip even though their x axis values are different.i.e points under the month of jan should have "11st comment" tooltip,points under Feb should have"22nd comment" tooltip so on and so forth even if their y axis values are same..I am trying to make that happen by replacing this.y with this.x as seen in this code http://jsfiddle.net/RbenU/27/ but it's not happening.Can you please tell me how to make that change?